# Wrapfigure in minipage effects the vertical separation of itemize

Tags: itemize, minipage, wrapfigure

I want to use wrapfigure in the enumerate environment. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol, lipsum, graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[5][1-6]
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{60pt}
        \includegraphics[width=60pt, height=30pt]{example-image} 
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \item \lipsum[5][7]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[5][8-9]
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[5][10]
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{50pt}
        \includegraphics[width=50pt, height=10pt]{example-image} 
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \item \lipsum[5][11-16]
    \end{minipage}
    \item \lipsum[5][17-18]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[5][19-]
\lipsum[6-7]
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[5][1-6]
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[5][7]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[5][8-9]
        \item \lipsum[5][10]
    \end{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[5][11-16]
    \item \lipsum[5][17-18]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[5][19-]
\lipsum[6-7]
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

(cf. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208436/243289)) However, it seems that the minipage effects (enlarges) the skip on the top and botton of the itemize eviroment:

[image]

Is there any way to reduce these redundant separations without modifying them one by one (by \vspace, for example)?

Comment: The documentation of `wrapfig` is very short but the one thing it does document is that it is incompatible with lists

Comment: Yes, I know that. Is there any alternative package to wrapfig?

Comment: I'm partial to paracol, although you have to manually break the paragraphs.  There is a package based on \hangindent instead of \parshape, but I can't remember the name.

Comment: Maybe it's https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/insbox?lang=en ? That's plain TeX, though, so you never know.

Answer (score 0):

First, `minipage` should go after `\item`.  The first `wrapfig` was replaced by simply reducing the width of the text.  The second `wrapfig` was replaced using `\hangindent` and overlapping the image.

For finer vertical placement, use `\raisebox` instead of `valign`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for [valign=...]
\usepackage{multicol, lipsum, graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[5][1-6]
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[5][7]
    \begin{itemize} 
      \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-60pt-\columnsep}
        \lipsum[5][8-9]
        \end{minipage}\hfill\includegraphics[width=60pt, height=30pt,valign=t]{example-image}
        
      \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \hangindent=-\dimexpr 50pt+\columnsep\relax
        \hangafter=-2
        \lipsum[5][10]
        \end{minipage}\llap{\includegraphics[width=50pt, height=10pt, valign=t]{example-image}}
    \end{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[5][11-16]
    \item \lipsum[5][17-18]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[5][19-]
\lipsum[6-7]
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[5][1-6]
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[5][7]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[5][8-9]
        \item \lipsum[5][10]
    \end{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[5][11-16]
    \item \lipsum[5][17-18]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[5][19-]
\lipsum[6-7]
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```