# Trouble formatting circuitikz with wrapfig and enumerate

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, circuitikz, wrapfigure, wrapfig

I'm trying to format a basic circuit question, where a circuit diagram is placed to the right of the choices in a multiple choice question.

Currently, it looks like

[image: incorrectly formatted multiple-choice question]

I'm after something that looks like, e.g.

[image: correctly formatted multiple-choice question]

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with the wrapfigure and enumerate environments. The circuit diagram is getting placed below the choices, rather than to their right. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{circuitikz} % for drawing circuit diagrams
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapfigure environment
\usepackage{enumitem} % more options for enumerate command

% define enumerate command for new multiple choice question
\newlist{mcquestion}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mcquestion,1]{label={\bfseries\arabic{mcquestioni}.}, leftmargin=*, resume=mcquestion}
\def\remembered[#1]{\typeout{Call #1:\arabic{mcquestioni}}}

% define enumerate command for possible choices
\newlist{mchoices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mchoices,1]{label={\bfseries\alph*.}, wide=1cm, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{mcquestion}
    \item In the circuit drawn in the figure, the ammeter has no resistance, and the battery has an e.m.f.~$\varepsilon$ and an internal resistance~$r$. Which of the following is correct?
\end{mcquestion}

\begin{mchoices}
    \item The current flowing through the ammeter is zero.
    \item The p.d. across the ammeter is zero.
    \item The potential drop \textbf{inside} the battery is zero.
    \item The energy dissipated in the whole circuit is zero.
\end{mchoices}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2] \draw
    (0,1)   to[battery, l={$\varepsilon$, r}]   (1,1)
    (1,1)   --                                  (1,0)
    (1,0)   to[rmeter, t=A]                     (0,0)
    (0,0)   --                                  (0,1)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Interesting question. Can you please add a screenshot of your current result? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, `wrapfig` and  *any* list-like environment are incompatible (see the [first bullet point on the first page of `wrapfig` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf)). You are much better using explicit minipages for it. (BTW, it has nothing to do with `circuitikz`, it would happen the same with any figure content).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208429/problem-with-wrapfig-and-itemize?rq=1

Comment: Mhhh... environment `problem` undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, `wrapfig` and list environments do not work well together, as noted by the manual (first page):

[image]

Although [you can help it work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208436/38080), I think that in this case, explicitly using a minipage is better (I changed `problem`, which is undefined, to `mquestion`):

```latex
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{circuitikz} % for drawing circuit diagrams
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapfigure environment
\usepackage{enumitem} % more options for enumerate command

% define enumerate command for new multiple choice question
\newlist{mquestion}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mquestion,1]{label={\bfseries\arabic{mquestioni}.}, leftmargin=*, resume=mquestion}
\def\remembered[#1]{\typeout{Call #1:\arabic{mquestioni}}}

% define enumerate command for possible choices
\newlist{mchoices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mchoices,1]{label={\bfseries\alph*.}, wide=1cm, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{mquestion}
    \item In the circuit drawn in the figure, the ammeter has no resistance, and the battery has an e.m.f.~$\varepsilon$ and an internal resistance~$r$. Which of the following is correct?
\end{mquestion}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
\begin{mchoices}
    \item The current flowing through the ammeter is zero.
    \item The p.d. across the ammeter is zero.
    \item The potential drop \textbf{inside} the battery is zero.
    \item The energy dissipated in the whole circuit is zero.
\end{mchoices}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2, baseline=(A.center)] \draw
    (0,1)   to[battery, l={$\varepsilon$, r}, name=A]   (1,1)
    (1,1)   --                                  (1,0)
    (1,0)   to[rmeter, t=A]                     (0,0)
    (0,0)   --                                  (0,1)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice how I fine-tuned the vertical position of the circuit with the `baseline` option (this is from Ti*k*Z).

Comment: Many thanks! I've slightly adjusted the formatting for aesthetic reasons, which others may find helpful, adding `\vspace{-1em}` before `\begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}\begin{mchoices}` and `\centering` the circuit diagram.